# How to create a countdown with flow coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I'm trying to create a flow with coroutines but it's not giving to me the expected result.
What I'd like to have is giving an expiration time (doesn't matter if it's in millis, seconds, etc..) when the time arrives to 0 it stops the countdown. What I have now is :

```
private fun tickerFlow(start: Long, end: Long = 0L) = flow {
        var count = start
        while (count >= end) {
            emit(Unit)
            count--
            delay(1_000L)
        }
    }
```

And then I call this function as :

```
val expireDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10L).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                tickerFlow(expireDate)
                    .map { LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) - expireDate }
                    .distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
                        old == new
                    }
                    .onEach {
                        //Here I should print the timer going down with this pattern 
                        //00h: 00m: 00s I did it with String.format("%02dh: %02dm: %02ds") and it works though.
                    }
                    .onCompletion {
                        //Setting the text when completed
                    }
                    .launchIn(scope = scope)
```

But even with this test that what I'm trying is to have the expiry time as 10 seconds from now it doesn't print nor end as I would. Am I missing something? Is there any way I could emit the local date time so I have the hours, minutes and seconds? perhaps I have to do the calculus to get the seconds, minutes hours from milis / seconds.

TLDR;

I'm getting from backend an expiry date, and I want to know when this expiry date finish so I have to calculate it with the now() and check when it is expired.

Comment: You want to get the current time in milliseconds repeatedly in an interval of 1 second, right?

Comment: @ArpitShukla what I want is, given an expire date calculate it with the current time that is now() and then check when this expire dates is over.

Comment: What should be the output? Something like 00:10:30 -> ... -> 00::05:15 -> ... -> 00:00:10 -> ... -> 00:00:01 -> stop?

Comment: Yes! exactly that

Comment: And when 00:00:00 it should jump to `onComplete()` so I can change the text of the TextView there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need a flow here. Try this code:

```kotlin
val expireDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10L).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
for (i in (expireDate - currentTime)  downTo 1) {
    println("$i seconds remaining") // Format the remaining seconds however you wish
    delay(1_000) // Delay for 1 second
}
println("TIME UP") // Run your completion code here
```

Also, this code is safe to run on main thread as `delay` doesn't block.

In your code, the problem is that you are passing the `expireDate` itself to `tickerFlow`. `expireDate` contains the time in seconds from epoch and not the seconds difference from current time. Just pass `expireDate - LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to tickerFlow  and it will work.

**EDIT:** Complete implementation using flow

```kotlin
private fun tickerFlow(start: Long, end: Long = 0L) = flow {
    for (i in start downTo end) {
        emit(i)
        delay(1_000)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val expireDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10L).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
tickerFlow(expireDate - currentTime)
    .onEach { secondsRemaining ->
        // Format and display the time
    }
    .onCompletion { 
        // Handle completion
    }
    .launchIn(scope)
```

Comment: Yes.. I know I can do it with this, but I'd like to know how to do it with `flow` thanks for your time though

Comment: Oh you want the flow version, give me a minute. Let me edit it.

Comment: Yes, following what I started I'd like to know what I was doing wrong there, just a countdown with flow and emit and collect

Comment: @StuartDTO See the edit.

Comment: What do I put in the .map{} and what do I emit? An Unit?

Comment: Keep everything the same and it will work, just that the counts will be negative (-10,-9,...-1,0). Although you can simplify this by directly emitting remainingSeconds from the flow but the current code will also work.

Comment: Want to add a sample code for that so I can mark your answer as a correct one?

Comment: Okay,  one minute.

Comment: No need to fool with ZoneOffset if you use Instant instead of LocalDateTime. `Instant.now().plusSeconds(10L).epochSecond`

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `flow`

```
private fun countDownFlow(
        start: Long,
        delayInSeconds: Long = 1_000L,
    ) = flow {
        var count = start
        while (count >= 0L) {
            emit(count--)
            delay(delayInSeconds)
        }
    }
```

And then given an expiration date, get the current date subtract them and pass it as start.

```
val expireDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10L).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
tickerFlow(expireDate - currentTime)
                    .onEach {
                        binding.yourTimer.text = String.format(
                            "%02dh: %02dm: %02ds",
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(it),
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(it),
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(it),
                        )
                    }
                    .onCompletion {
                        //Update UI
                    }
                    .launchIn(coroutineScope)
```

Answer (score 0):

If in hurry copy/paste this!

```kotlin
     fun getFlow( delayTimeMilliseconds: Long,  startValue: Long,  stepValue : Long = 1,  endValue : Long =0): Flow<Long> =
            ( startValue downTo  endValue step  stepValue ).asFlow().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                    .onEach { delay( delayTimeMilliseconds) } 
                    .onStart { emit( startValue) } 
                    .conflate()
                    .transform { remainingValue: Long ->
                        if(remainingValue<0) emit(0)
                        else emit( remainingValue)
                    }
```

On my production app I use  timer as an UseCase as per clean architecture. Like this :

```kotlin
class TimerFlowUseCase constructor() : StateFlowUseCase<TimerFlowUseCase.Params, Long>() {

    override suspend fun getFlow(params: Params): Flow<Long> =
            (params.startValue downTo params.endValue step params.stepValue ).asFlow().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                    .onEach { delay(params.delayTimeMilliseconds) } 
                    .onStart { emit(params.startValue) } // Emits total value on start
                    .conflate()  
                    .transform { remainingValue: Long ->
                        if(remainingValue<0) emit(0)
                        else emit( remainingValue)
                    }

    data class Params( val delayTimeMilliseconds: Long, val startValue: Long, val stepValue : Long = 1, val endValue : Long =0)
}
```

Where superclass is:

```kotlin
abstract class StateFlowUseCase<P, R> {
    suspend operator fun invoke(params: P , coroutineScope: CoroutineScope): StateFlow<R> {
        return getFlow(params).stateIn(coroutineScope)
    }
    abstract suspend fun getFlow(params: P): Flow<R>
}
```